UK Visa Roundtrip Courier Service
I bought the round trip courier service but received only one pdf file which has my own address, I'm guessing I'll have to put it inside the envelope in which I'll send my documents. Should I have also got something more? I'm wondering how round trip service is different from return service?
Please help.

There are quite a few previous questions about VFS courier service, for your interest.
